# How do I un-comment lines in this configuration file?

Tags: configuration, editors

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

Comment: Don't know how to do what? It's not clear what you are asking help for. And what does this have to do with `sed` as tagged?

Comment: my command was-  $ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to do? You haven't actually explained that or even asked a question.

Comment: i cant install  adobe flash player. im really new at terminal. i read in a forum that this canonical repo is keeping me from this

Comment: Please read your question and think about whether it makes any sense to anyone except yourself. How can people help if you don't even tell us you were trying to install `adobe`? Put in the commands you ran to try the install and the exact errors that you encountered.

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: Remove `#` from the start of the last two lines.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Do you know how to use an editor in Linux? Try run `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` or use any editor you are familiar with. If you don't even know how to use an editor then best if you read up on Linux basics as it will be difficult to cover such basics in this forum.

Comment: i know how to use an editor. i started  to learn linux last wednesday. erased my windows ten and loaded ubuntu. best way to learn is head first right....lol thank you for your help.

Comment: duplicate post ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560570/how-to-uncomment-two-lines-in-nano-etc-apt-sources-list-permission-denied

Answer (score 0):

To enable `partner` repository , use `add-apt-repository` tool:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

To remove the partner repository , use `-r` option :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

**To answer the question**, you can edit the `sources.list` through a text editor/utility. e,g:

```
sudo editor /etc/apt/sources.list
```

using `sed` to un-comment the lines endings with `partner` :

```
sudo sed -i '/partner$/s/^#//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to remove white space at the beginning of lines:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^ *//' /etc/apt/sources.list
```